# condition to swap two sprite in c++ for cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am developing a game in cocos2d-x. In that game I am having two sprites, When i click on a sprite one after another it should swap.I don't know the code for that please help.I created the sprite using following code.

```
  CCSprite *splash=CCSprite::create("misc_textur111.jpg");

   splash->setPosition(ccp(500,300));

    this->addChild(splash,1);


CCSprite *splash1=CCSprite::create("misc_textur222.jpg");

splash1->setPosition(ccp(300,600));

this->addChild(splash,1)
```

Now I need to swap the position of both the images.please help.

Comment: Please be more specific about swap. Just the position or all value?

Comment: i need to swap their position?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
CCPoint position(splash->getPosition());
splash->setPosition(splash1->getPosition());
splash1->setPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, if you can, upgrading to a newer release of Cocos2d-x. Version 2.23 or even better, version 3.v. Dragging sprites around is trivial with the new `EventDispatcher` You can create a `Listener` for each Sprite.

Example:

```
//Create a "one by one" touch event listener (processes one touch at a time)
auto listener1 = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
// When "swallow touches" is true, then returning 'true' from the onTouchBegan method will "swallow" the touch event, preventing other listeners from using it.
listener1->setSwallowTouches(true);

//Trigger when moving touch
listener1->onTouchMoved = [](Touch* touch, Event* event){
    auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
    //Move the position of current button sprite
    target->setPosition(target->getPosition() + touch->getDelta());
};
```

Check out the Cocos2d-x Wiki: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki